# Executing javascript inside Handlebars template

Tags: javascript, template-engine, handlebars.js

I'm totally new to js template engines. Handlebars seems to be the popular choice. I don't dislike the syntax for doing conditions, loops and so on, but since I'm perfectly capable of and feel more comfortable using plain old js and I'm not planning to let anyone who doesn't know js touch my templates, I'm asking if Handlebars  supports this.

Of course the most popular choice isn't always the best. I'm more of a Mootools guy and jQuery drives me crazy(great library, just not for me). So if Handlebars was jQuery of template engines, what would be Mootools?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the central ideas behind handlebars and [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) is they are **[LOGICLESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896730/whats-the-advantage-of-logic-less-template-such-as-mustache)** by design and intention. They can not now, nor will [they](http://handlebarsjs.com/) ever allow or recommend you embed raw JS in your templates. Some say this is a better design. If you want embedded javascript, almost every other traditional templating engine, such as [_.template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) or [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) or [EJS](https://ejs.co/) is based on (or at least supports) the idea of embedded JS code snippets.

Comment: +1 for suggesting EJS. At a quick glance it seems to be just what I needed.

Comment: I read a little more about the philosophy of logicless templates and I have to say that I kind of agree with some of the ideas. That said, I don't really agree that logic should be disallowed just because someone else might abuse it. Nevertheless, reading about logicless has given me valuable insight and I recommend the same for anyone facing the same question as I did.

Comment: where can i drop a debug statement in handle bar source to inspect the scope of the template? I am lazy and don`t want to live in my debugger/code .

Comment: If you mean the `debugger` keyword, you can't. Best you can do is add a breakpoint/debugger right before you call the template function to render and step into the compiled function. But you can do something like <--{{someKey}}--> if you just want to see what values are in scope.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry to resurrect a old issue here. If you have to use handlebars or it's not feasible to change your templating library you can use Helpers from the Handlebars library.

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers

Comment: The link seem to have migrated here https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers

Answer (score 0):

Registering a helper in handlebar can be a walk around to what you are trying to do. See this link for a complete example: [Registering handlebars helpers with node does absolutely nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089958/registering-handlebars-helpers-with-node-does-absolutely-nothing)