# Registering handlebars helpers with node does absolutely nothing

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm attempting to write my own handlebars helpers and am getting no where. I'm using the npm hbs package (Handlebars.registerHelper didn't work) and registering it in app.js like so:

```
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
var hbs = require('hbs');

hbs.registerHelper("log", function(something) {
    return console.log(something);
});

hbs.registerHelper('test', function() { 
  return console.log('test')
});
```

Yet {{log 'test'}} or {{test}} any where inside my template does absolutely nothing. There's no js errors being produced in the browser or terminal consoles. I know handle bars is working correctly since I have other hb variables displaying correctly. I'm at my wits end here trying to do something very simple otherwise I wouldn't embarrasses my self by asking such a simple question.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for your input mscdex but your response didn't work. I'll clarify how I got it working here for others new to handlebars. I was using the npm hbs package because I found good helper examples. After looking into it deeper, my previous handlebars package "express-handlebars" had some examples on the npm page that actually worked. I think my main confusion was a result of not knowing where the first variable in the declaration was being defined.

Below is the code in my app.js file that declares which handlebars package to use.

```
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Then in the route for a particular page the helper is defined the same way the title or an array of data would be:

```
res.render('editSite', {
      title: 'Update Existing Site\'s Data', siteVars: siteVars, helpers: {
            foo: function () { return console.log('test'); }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well... Where was hbs being set?

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually return a string from your helpers. `console.log()` returns `undefined`. Try this instead:

```
hbs.registerHelper("log", function(something) {
  console.log(something);
  return ''+something;
});

hbs.registerHelper('test', function() { 
  console.log('test');
  return 'test';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

in my view, the simpliest way to do what you want, if this is about global helpers (may not be the best solution, but...), is to create your helpers file :

```
module.exports = {
    customif: (options)=>{
        return (options.hash.expected === options.hash.val) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    }
}
```

Then, require it :

```
const handlebarsHelpers = require('./helpers/handlebars');
```

And finally, when you link express to handlebars, you can insert helpers in the object :

```
app.engine('hbs', handlebars({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/',
    helpers: handlebarsHelpers
}));
```

And you can use it inside your layout `blabla.hbs`:

```
{{#customif expected='foo' val=field}}
    bar
{{/customif}}
```

Works for me...