# How is Mustache "logic-less"?

Tags: php, javascript, templates, logic, mustache

[Definition of "logic"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20logic&oq=define%20logic&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1416j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> Reasoning conducted or assessed according to strict principles of
>   validity: "experience is a better guide to this than deductive logic".

Mustache's "sections" use conditional logic in the form of displaying blocks based on the value of a boolean, [from the documentation](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html):

Template:

```
Shown.
{{#nothin}}
  Never shown!
{{/nothin}}
```

Hash:

```
{
  "person": true,
}
```

Output:

```
Shown.
```

I'm therefore curios to learn in what manner is Mustache deemed "logic-less" if logic under my (likely naive/ignorant) definition occurs within its templates?

Comment: From wikipedia: `Mustache is described as a "logic-less" system because it lacks any explicit control flow statements, like if and else conditionals or for loops; however, both looping and conditional evaluation can be achieved using section tags processing lists and lambdas.`

Comment: Isn't that an oxymoron though? Because if conditional evaluation can be achieved (regardless of syntax) it contains logic?

Answer (score 1):

It's called "logic-less" compared to many other template systems. I don't think any particularly deep claim is intended. The answers to [What's the advantage of Logic-less template (such as mustache)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896730/whats-the-advantage-of-logic-less-template-such-as-mustache?rq=1) may be enlightening as well.